# A margin is appearing within the page which is not required in a my own made wordpress theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I am facing problem with a my own made wordpress theme. a margin is appearing within the page which is not required. please help. i am in a hurry.
This is the site i am working on. http://wp.balessing.net/

i want this thing. 
http://unizhost.com/a/mavrickit/

See the margin between the image slider of the SECTIONS WE SERVE and the RED LINE is very big in my theme. why is this happening.
Please HELP. I have less time to complete the work.

Thaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get rid of `height: 1839px;` on `<div id="bigest">` You can space your content afterwards using margin-top and bottom.

PS: and learn to use Chrome DevTools CSS inspector.

Answer (score 0):

In the div tag biggest please use the CSS as seen here its show the result what you want.

```
#bigest {
    background: url("image/usa.png") no-repeat scroll center 0 transparent;
    height:auto;
    margin: 50px auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have fixed it by decreasing the height of BIGEST.